# ¿Cómo obtener en una variable el contenido de un directorio con javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Es posible hacer que en una variable tipo array se grabe el contenido de una carpeta para luego recorrer el mismo y mostrar cada elemento en `HTML`

El contenido que va a tener dicha carpeta son imágenes y el contenido de la misma solo puede ser modificado por el administrador o dueño del sitio.

Me pregunto esto ya que no me gustaría tener que especificar una etiqueta `<img/>` para cada imagen sino en un script tener un array para recorrerlo y mediante otra variable de texto escribir la etiqueta con el atributo src  para obtener cada elemento del array y al final mostar el contenido de la variable con un innerHTML en el elemento contenedor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible.

Al menos no desde cliente, claro está. Desde servidor podrías utilizar `fs`, por ejemplo.

Alternativas (bastante cutres, la verdad):

Una opción, dependiendo del servidor de archivos y de cómo esté configurado, sería hacer una petición ajax a la ruta y que esa ruta devolviese el listado de archivos, pudiendo parsearlo como html y devolviendo los nodos, pero lo más probable es que te encuentres con un 403.

Otra opción sería que se genere, con un cron por ejemplo, un fichero que tenga el listado de archivos para luego leerlo.